# Как сгладить углы кривой, используя Python?

Tags: python, graphics, vector

Доброго времени суток!

У меня такой вопрос: имеется кривая (представлена как `numpy array`) с острыми углами, которые мне нужно сгладить. Мне хотелось бы заменить "углы" на сектор окружности с определенным радиусом.

У меня была идея преобразовать кривую в тип `LineString` пакета `Shapely`, и затем воспользоваться `line.parallel_offset`. Но я не понимаю, что именно эта функция возвращает и как это преобразовать обратно к координатам.

Кто-нибудь пользовался `shapely` и знает, как оно вообще работает? Или мне не обязательно городить огород с shapely и можно добиться цели более простым путем?

Заранее спасибо за помощь и прошу прощения, если вопрос элементарный.

Comment: numpy.array - это просто массив, если я не ошибаюсь. Как вы его отрисовываете? Как вариант решения навскидку - рисуйте обычную кривую с острыми углами (как я понял, речь идет о кривой определенной толщины, у которой углы при отрисовке по 90 градусов), а на концах круг диаметром в толщину кривой. Если же надо не круглые концы, а закругленные, используйте на каждом конце по два круга и прямоугольник.

Comment: @therainycat не забывайте про "определенный радиус". Из вопроса не ясно, на сколько он определен, правда :)

Comment: Обязательно нужен сектор окружности определенного радиуса? Если так, то непонятно, как его размещать - добавьте изображение. Или вам нужно что-то типа border-radius в css (пример https://www.cssmatic.com/border-radius)?

Comment: @therainycat вопрос не мой, потому не могу сказать :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич не туда глянул :) Про определенный радиус не забыл, в части про два круга и прямоугольник как раз об этом речь.